# How to connect my local development environment to localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, mysql, localhost

I want to configure my applications to run on localhost, but only 127.0.0.1 works. `localhost` gives me a PDO error, or a database connection error, while `127.0.0.1` runs fine. I run into this issue working in a local development environment with both WordPress and Drupal. I'm using mysql with the built in apache server on OSX.

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

from with mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Typical error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
```

And then when I switch the host entry to `127.0.0.1` the application runs fine.

What I'm looking for is how to leave the host configured as localhost but still connect to the database.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this one: http://serverfault.com/a/295300/196365

Comment: that looks like it's the issue, connecting on TCP instead of unix socket, except the result of `netstat -ln | grep 'mysql'` is `/tmp/mysql.sock`. I think this means it's connecting through the socket. I placed a `/etc/my.cnf` to connect to that socket as well, the result is the same.

Comment: Digging in a little further, when I directly connect to mysql from the command line and run the `\s` command I find that I'm connecting on the unix socket. So perhaps the issue I'm running into is at the application level and not the mysql system.